# binary search trees in ruby

Tags: ruby, binary-tree

Is there a reason why I don't see binary search trees used much in Ruby?

Is there an equivalent data structure or class that people typically use instead?

I'm not trying to solve a specific problem; just trying to learn more about the language.

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Binary search trees are a relatively low-level implementation detail, usually for a map/table abstract data type. In Ruby, if you want a map/table, you just use a Hash.  If you have a problem that specifically needs binary search trees, there's also a good chance a Ruby implementation will be too slow to be useful.